# multiline FormInput element goes off screen

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, jsx, styling

I've created a simple popup for a form with react-native-elements. The problem is that the second form input is meant to be multiline, and if the text has too many lines, the element overflows outside the bottom of the popup, pushing the submit button off the screen. A bonus would be getting the submit button to position itself at the bottom of the popup. Here's the code, I've also embedded it inside a snack for ease https://snack.expo.io/HyZPSSj8m

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

import { Card, FormLabel, FormInput, FormValidationMessage, Button } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Card containerStyle={styles.popup} title="Add text">

              <FormLabel>Title</FormLabel>
              <FormInput inputStyle={{width: undefined}}/>

              <FormLabel>Text</FormLabel>
              <FormInput multiline numberOfLines={5} inputStyle={{width: undefined}} />
              <Button buttonStyle={styles.popupButton} title="Submit" />
          </Card>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'stretch'
  },
  popup: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 10,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    flex: 1
  },
  popupButton: {
    borderRadius: 0, 
    marginLeft: 0, 
    marginRight: 0, 
    marginBottom: 10,
    marginTop: 10
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer that at least works for now. The ideal situation would be to make the FormInput take up as much space as possible without overflowing. To solve the problem, I set the `maxHeight` property to 200. Works well enough for now, but I'll leave the question open in case any one comes up with a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your Views with ScrollView.

```
 export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
       <Card containerStyle={styles.popup} title="Add text">

          <FormLabel>Title</FormLabel>
          <FormInput inputStyle={{width: undefined}}/>

          <FormLabel>Text</FormLabel>
          <FormInput multiline numberOfLines={5} inputStyle={{width: undefined}} />
          <Button buttonStyle={styles.popupButton} title="Submit" />
      </Card>
     </ScrollView>
    );
   }
  }
```

Comment: Did you try this first? It doesn't work, the Card becomes squished

Comment: Take out the position: 'absolute' from popup.

Comment: Okay, but this makes the entire popup scrollable. I want the popup to stay in the same spot.